# why numpy array dimension (8, 900)@(900, 3, 3, 3) doesn't work?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I've been trying to multiply two numpy arrays, which have dimension (8, 900) and (900, 3, 3, 3), and expecting the result dimension like (8,3,3,3), but an error below occurs. What's wrong with my thought?

ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 3 is different from 900)

Comment: What do you expect to happen?  I think this is erroring because your smaller array is not broadcastable https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-broadcasting-with-numpy-arrays/ over the larger one.

Comment: According to `matmul` docs, it's the last dimension of A that matches with the **2nd to last** of B. The 2nd 900 is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [39]: A = np.random.rand(8,900)
In [40]: B = np.random.rand(900,3,3,3)
```

For complicated dimensions mixes like this, `einsum` is easy to use:

```
In [41]: C = np.einsum('ij,jklm->iklm', A, B)
In [42]: C.shape
Out[42]: (8, 3, 3, 3)
```

To use `@/matmul` we have to do a transpose, since the `j/900` dimension has to be 2nd to the last in the 2nd argument:

```
In [43]: B1 = B.transpose(1,2,0,3)
In [44]: B1.shape
Out[44]: (3, 3, 900, 3)
In [45]: D = A @ B1
In [46]: D.shape
Out[46]: (3, 3, 8, 3)
```

`matmul` does a `dot` on the last 2 dimensions of the arrays, and treats the leading ones as `batch` dimensions.

Now this shape is not quite what you want, but we can transpose it

```
In [48]: D1 = D.transpose(2,0,1,3)
In [49]: np.allclose(C,D1)
Out[49]: True
```

The leading dimensions of `A` and `B1` broadcasted, so it should be possible to tweak them to get the `8` first directly, but I'm having some problems getting that right.

But come to think of it, `dot's` broadcasting might be what we want:

```
In [50]: E=A.dot(B1)
In [51]: E.shape
Out[51]: (8, 3, 3, 3)
In [52]: np.allclose(C,E)
Out[52]: True
```

The main difference between `matmul` and `dot` is in the handling of the leading dimensions.  `dot` does broadcasting`,` matmul` treats them as batches, with different broadcasting rules.

Timings:

```
In [53]: timeit E=A.dot(B.transpose(1,2,0,3))
393 µs ± 219 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [54]: timeit C = np.einsum('ij,jklm->iklm', A, B)
247 µs ± 226 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [55]: timeit (A@B.transpose(1,2,0,3)).transpose(2,0,1,3)
196 µs ± 181 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use *@* operator to multiply 2 arrays, e.g.
`arr_1 @ arr_2` then:

- the first array should have shape *(i,j)*,
- the second array should have shape *(j,k)*,
- arrays can have more dimensions, but the "basic" variant is when
  they are both 2-D arrays.

Note that *j* - the second dimension of *arr_1* must be just
the same as the first dimension of *arr_2*.

But your arrays don't meet these requirements.

Probably to get your expected result you should run:

```
result = np.einsum('ij,jklm->iklm', arr_1, arr_2)
```

(for details read about *np.einsum*).

To check the above code, create both (smaller) test arrays as:

```
shp_1 = (5, 4); shp_2 = (4, 3, 3, 3)
arr_1 = np.arange(1, np.prod(shp_1) + 1).reshape(shp_1)
arr_2 = np.arange(1, np.prod(shp_2) + 1).reshape(shp_2)
```

Then, to trace e.g. how element *[0, 0, 0, 0]* of the result is computed,
run:

```
i = 0; k = 0; l = 0; m = 0
l1 = arr_1[i]
l2 = arr_2[:, k, l, m]
print(np.vstack([l1, l2]))
print(l1 * l2)
print((l1 * l2).sum())
```

For the above arrays the result (with my comments) is:

```
[[ 1  2  3  4]      # l1
 [ 1 28 55 82]]     # l2
[  1  56 165 328]   # l1 * l2
550                 # The element of the result
```

Repeat the above procedure for other combination of indices in *result*.